# Solving for unknown input variable on time series function

Tags: calculus, algebra-precalculus

I was referred from StackOverflow after struggling to solve an equation for an unknown within a decline equation. The function determines a cumulative value given an initial rate(q) and terminal rate (r) over a period of time (t) and given constant (n). This is based on Arps decline equations  I've been trying to backsolve for an unknown q given the other parameters.

**u** = cumulative value

**t** = time to from initial (q) to terminal (v)

**q** = initial rate

**v** = terminal rate

**n** = constant

First,  **(q≫v)** $$ r= \frac{q(unknown)}{v(known)}$$

Second, the equation for cumulutive value u, is: $$u = \frac{qtn}{1-n} \biggl[\frac{(\frac{1}{r})^n -(\frac{1}{r})}{1-(\frac{1}{r})^n}\biggl]  $$

by inserting **r** in I get: $$Solve for q,u = \frac{qtn}{1-n} \biggl[\frac{(\frac{v}{q})^n -(\frac{v}{q})}{1-(\frac{v}{q})^n}\biggl]  $$

This is where I'm stuck at present. I'm trying to solve for the intial **q**, given **u**, **t**,**n**, and terminal value **v**. I did try using Symbolab to help but it could not resolve the equation unfortunately.

At present, I'm looking at trying to implement [Newton's method](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newton%27s_method) to see if I can sample and converge to a solution for q. Any insight is greatly appreciated.

Many thanks in advance and apologies if this posted with the incorrect Tag.

Comment: How does $q$ compare to $v$ ?

Comment: (q) is the initial value and (v) is the terminal over time (t) which yields a cumulative value (u).  We actually write this as $$r= \frac{qi}{qt}$$ but I opted to alias it here minimize confusion.

Comment: Please, tell me if $q\gg v$ or $q \ll v$

Comment: Thanks Claude,  q ≫ v

Comment: Since I cannot now comment on the other post you made, thanks for understanding and migrating it here!

Comment: Thank you....I want to ensure to keep with the intent and spirit of each community!